# Capistrano - cleaning up old releases issue

Tags: capistrano

I followed the advice in another post about how to clean up old capistrano releases, however, i've realised that the way I've implemented this has messed up the paths in my application (just on a staging site thankfully!). I am using the code below in my config/deploy/staging.rb script, but it can't be running at the correct point, as after deployment I end up with application failing as it's trying to load classes from earlier releases. If I remove the `keep_releases` line and the one below, and redeploy, everything works again. Has anyone come across this issue?

```
set :use_sudo, false
set :keep_releases, 1
after "deploy:update", "deploy:cleanup"

namespace :deploy do
  task :symlink_shared do
    // run some commands i need
  end
end

before "deploy:restart", "deploy:symlink_shared"
```

Answer (score 0):

So it seems the order wasn't right - I changed `keep_releases` to 2, removed the line underneath and then changed the last line to the following:

```
"deploy:update", "deploy:symlink_shared"
after "deploy:restart", "deploy:cleanup"
```